# Can tkinter styles be extended or combined?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Let's say I have a style for a button.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
ttk.Style(root).configure('Border.TButton', borderwidth=4, relief='raised')
```

I want another style which extends the existing one. For example with `font=('Helvetica', 24)`. Currently I am hardcoding everything from the `'Border.TButton'` style like this:

```
ttk.Style(root).configure('BorderBigFont.TButton', borderwidth=4, relief='raised', font=('Helvetica', 24))
```

Is there a better way?

**Pseudo-code** of what I am asking (how I wish it worked):

```
ttk.Style(root).configure('BorderBigFont.TButton', font=('Helvetica', 24), extends='Border.TButton')
```

or alternatively, when setting a style

```
ttk.Style(root).configure('BigFont.TButton', font=('Helvetica', 24))
ttk.Button(root, text='foo', style=['Border.TButton', 'BigFont.TButton'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: `tkinter.Style` be extended or combined?

1. Define your own `class Style` by inheriting from `class ttk.Style`.
2. Overload method `.configure(...` to implement `extend=`.

   1. Save every `kwargs=` options into the instance attribute `self._style`.
   2. On argument `extend=`, pre `.configure(...` using the options saved in `self._style[...]`.
   3. Forward to the original `ttk.Style.configure(...`.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Style(ttk.Style):
    EXTENDS = 'extends'

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._style = {}

    def configure(self, cls, **kwargs):
        self._style.setdefault(cls, {}).update(kwargs)

        extends = self._style.get(kwargs.get(Style.EXTENDS), {})
        super().configure(cls, **extends)

        super().configure(cls, **kwargs)
```

> **Usage**:
>
> **Note**: To change only the font size, use `None`: `font=(None, ...`.

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        buttonbox = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

        style = Style(self)
        style.theme_use('clam')

        style.configure('Border.TButton', 
                        font=('Helvetica', 10), borderwidth=4, relief='raised')

        style.configure('BorderBigFont.TButton',
                        font=(None, 24),
                        extends='Border.TButton')

        style.configure('BorderRed.TButton',
                        bordercolor='red',
                        extends='Border.TButton')

        for _style in ['Border.TButton', 'BorderBigFont.TButton', 'BorderRed.TButton']:
            btn = ttk.Button(buttonbox, text=_style, style=_style)
            btn.grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize that one style object is enough.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the layout of the style?