# tkinter ttk copy Style layout

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I found this solution to extend a ttk theme:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Style(ttk.Style):
    EXTENDS = 'extends'

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._style = {}

    def configure(self, cls, **kwargs):
        self._style.setdefault(cls, {}).update(kwargs)

        extends = self._style.get(kwargs.get(Style.EXTENDS), {})
        super().configure(cls, **extends)

        super().configure(cls, **kwargs)
```

My question is: How to make it to copy the Style layout of the Style, that it extends?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can tkinter styles be extended or combined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158208/can-tkinter-styles-be-extended-or-combined)

Comment: This only solved half of my problem.